# Limit of $\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+12}-4)}{2-\sqrt{x^3-4}}$ as $x$ goes to 2

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> $$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+12}-4}{2-\sqrt{x^3-4}}$$

I know it must be very trivial, but yet I'm stuck at this problem and other similar problems for quite a long time. I'd be glad if someone showed me a full solution *without using L'Hospital* and delighted if someone could give some hints about *how to atack this kind of problem*... what is the thinking behind? Is it just about intuition? Or is it about test all sort of algebraic manipulation?

Comment: Try multiplying and dividing by the conjugate of both the numerator and denominator.

Comment: I've tried, but I coudn't find a (x-2) in the denominator. There is where I'm stuck.

Comment: For a different approach, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that
$$\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+12}-4}{2 - \sqrt{x^3-4}} = \lim_{x \to 2 }\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+12}-4)(\sqrt{x^2+12}+4)(2 + \sqrt{x^3-4})}{(2 - \sqrt{x^3-4})(\sqrt{x^2+12}+4)(2 + \sqrt{x^3-4})} = \lim_{x \to 2}\frac{(x^2-4)(2 + \sqrt{x^3-4})}{(8-x^3)(\sqrt{x^2+12}+4)}$$

Then you can use that the limit of a product is a product of the limits.

$$=\underbrace{\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{2+\sqrt{x^3-4}}{(4 + \sqrt{x^2+12})}}_{=1/2}\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{(x^2-4)}{(8-x^3)} = -\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{x+2}{x^2+2x+4}}_{=1/3} = -\frac{1}{6}$$

Where, after using $8-x^3 = - (x^3-8)$ and $x^2-4=(x-2)(x+2)$ we noted that

$$(x^3 - 8) = (x - 2)(x^2 + 2x + 4)$$

In general you are correct in the way of treat this kind of problems. This type of manipulations of polynomials are very useful: when you get a polynomial such as $x^3-8$ and it is easy to see that $x=2$ is a root you can divide by $x-2$ and lower the order of the polynomial.

Comment: But this  way the limit would be 0, right? The answer is -1\6

Comment: There is a problem I'm fixing it

Comment: Now gives the correct answer, sorry

Comment: Oh, I had made the same mistake! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Since you already received good answers, let me show you another way.

Since $x\to 2$, define $x=y+2$ which makes 
$$A=\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+12}-4}{2-\sqrt{x^3-4}}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{y^2+4 y+16}-4}{2-\sqrt{y^3+6 y^2+12 y+4}}$$ Since $y$ is small, we can neglect $y^2$ and $y^3$ which makes $$A\sim\frac{\sqrt{4 y+16}-4}{2-\sqrt{12 y+4}}$$ Now, using the generalized binomial theorem (or Taylor series)
$$\sqrt{4 y+16}=4+\frac{y}{2}+\cdots$$ $$\sqrt{12 y+4}=2+3 y+\cdots$$ from which you can easily conclude.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get used to the standard limit $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^{n} - a^{n}}{x - a} = na^{n - 1}$$ which solves these algebraic limit problems instantly.

Thus we have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 2}\frac{\sqrt{x^{2} + 12} - 4}{2 - \sqrt{x^{3} - 4}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 2}\frac{\sqrt{x^{2} + 12} - \sqrt{16}}{(x^{2} + 12) - 16}\cdot\frac{x^{2} - 4}{8 - x^{3}}\cdot\frac{4 - (x^{3} - 4)}{\sqrt{4} - \sqrt{x^{3} - 4}}\notag\\
&= -\lim_{t \to 16}\frac{t^{1/2} - 16^{1/2}}{t - 16}\cdot\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{x^{2} - 2^{2}}{x - 2}\cdot\frac{x - 2}{x^{3} - 2^{3}}\cdot\lim_{u \to 4}\frac{u - 4}{u^{1/2} - 4^{1/2}}\text{ (}u = x^{3} - 4, t = x^{2} + 12)\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\cdot 16^{-1/2}\cdot 2\cdot 2^{1}\cdot\frac{1}{3\cdot 2^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 4^{-1/2}}\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{4}\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{6}\notag
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt { x^2 + 12}, g(x) = \sqrt { x^3 -4}.$ The expression equals

$$\tag 1-\frac{f(x) - f(2)}{g(x) - g(2)} = -\,\,\dfrac{\dfrac{f(x) - f(2)}{x-2}}{\dfrac{g(x) - g(2)}{x-2}}.$$

By definition of the derivative, the numerator on the right of $(1)$ has limit $f'(2),$ the denominator has limit $g'(2).$ Thus the desired limit is $-f'(2)/g'(2),$ an easy computation.